# Write Java Code to execute SQL Group By

Tags: java, sql, file

We would typically write Oracle SQL to find max salary of every employee in each department if we had a table with `EmpID`, `DeptID`, `Salary`:

```
select EmpID,DeptID, rank over(partition by DeptID order by Salary) rnk
from Table
where rnk=1;
```

OR

```
select EmpID
from Table1
where Salary =(Select max(Salary) from Table2 group by DeptID
               and Table2.DeptId = Table1.DeptId )
```

If the above table was a file instead, then how can we write custom Java code to implement the same behavior?

Comment: looks like you are using oracle... can you use external table? or just load the file using sqlloder? - [external table](http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i.php#basic_usage)

you can certainly do this in java but you have to parse the file  and maintain a map/structure to produce that number

Comment: Do you mean *instead* of SQL?

Comment: Are there multiple entries in the table for each EmpID?  Can an EmpID be in multiple departments?  Would they have multiple salaries?  You need to supply some more context so that we can better understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, why don't you implement it by reading the file and passing it to the library of your choice for querying? Or by using Hibernate, and then passing the read file as:

```
Session.createSQLQuery(fromReadFile)
```

and

```
Session.createSQLQuery(fromReadFile).uniqueResults()
```

to get the results as a List or a particular object?